# Why my button is not calling action in the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have EDITSTORIES partial view which must post data to UpdateStories action in Stories controller but it doesn't. It doesn't even hit the breakpoint.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateStories", "Stories", FormMethod.Post, new{enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Stories</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Image, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Story, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Story, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Story, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Action:

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateStories(Stories st)
        {    
            ViewBag.Grid= bo.GetAllImages();

            if (bo.UpdateImages(st))
            {
                ViewBag.Data = "Updated successfully";
            }
            else 
            {
                ViewBag.Data = "Update failed";
            }

            ViewBag.Style = "display:none";    
            return View("GetStories", st);   
        }
    }
```

It's inside the GetStories which is the main view. It's been a long day and still, it hasn't been done. Please help me with it.

Update:

Routes:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Stories", action = "AddStories", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ShowStories",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Stories", action = "ShowStories", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Update:

View: GetStories

```
@model HimHer.Models.Stories

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (@Html.BeginForm("GetStories", "Stories", FormMethod.Get))
{
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div style="@ViewBag.Style">
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("EditStories", Model);
        }


    </div>

    <hr />
    var listData = (List<HimHer.Models.Stories>)ViewBag.Grid;

    WebGrid wgImages = new WebGrid(listData, rowsPerPage: 20);
    @wgImages.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive",
columns: wgImages.Columns(
                      wgImages.Column
                      (columnName: "Image", header: "Image"),
                      wgImages.Column
                      (columnName: "Story", header: "Story"),
                      wgImages.Column
                      (columnName: "Image", header: "Download", format: (testItem) => Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadStories", new { filename = testItem.Image })),
                      wgImages.Column
                                         (header: "Edit", format: (testitem) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditStories", new { ID = testitem.ID, Story = testitem.Story, Image = testitem.Image, HiddenID = 1 }))
                     )
);



}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

Comment: What's the status code for the form post response?

Comment: You haven't shown your routes in the question. Or the name of the controller.

Comment: @mason udpated and contoller is STORIES

Comment: @Jasen: none, it takes me back to GetStories

Comment: 1. What HTML is rendered for this page? Can you confirm that form actions are correct? 2. Maybe you have some nested forms on page?.

Comment: single form, and there is no view for this action, only action.

Comment: but you are rendering this partial somewhere right? Render.Partial( ...partialName ). To what it is rendering? <form method="post" action="<what action is here?>".

Comment: So when you click the button, what is happening now, Is it posting to somewhere or nothing happens ?

Comment: it takes me to getstories and I put breakpoint, it doesn't hit that

Comment: @Shyju action="/Stories/GetStories" method=''get''

Comment: @PiotrPasieka action="/Stories/GetStories"

Comment: Html.RenderPartial("EditStories", Model);

Comment: With the code you posted, the form tag's action should be '/Stories/UpdateStories`.  Where are you seeing **action="/Stories/GetStories" method=''get''** ?

Comment: in get stories view, where i have put  Html.RenderPartial("EditStories", Model); and this is rendering to /Stories/GetStories

Comment: So you have the GetStories view, inside which you are rendering this partial ?  Do you have another form tag in the GetStories view ? (Nested forms)

Comment: @Shyju just a beginform for getstories and then partialview rendering

Comment: @Shyju I have updated my code: check

Comment: That is the problem! You cannot have nested forms!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code will generate 2 forms and they are nested!.

```
<form action="/Stories/GetStories">
   <form action="/Stories/UpdateStories">
      <input type="submit" />
   </form>
</form>
```

**Nested forms are invalid!** This is the reason, when you click the submit button from inner form from the partial view, it is submitting to the action method defined for the outer form.

You should not be nesting forms. So move out the call to the RenderPartial outside of your `BeginForm` call.

Looking at the code you shared,there is no need to have the form tag in the main view as you do not have any form data you have to submit. So simply remove that.

If you absolutely want another form in the main view, make sure that, it is not creating a nested form situation. You can have 2 forms parallel in the same view

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("GetStories", "Stories", FormMethod.Get))
{
   <!-- Some form elements needed for this form -->     

}

@{ Html.RenderPartial("EditStories", Model); }
```